# boolean method canPaste() does not return false even when the condition is satisfied

Tags: java, methods, boolean, clipboard, paste

when the String cpbtxt is null, the method should return false but it does not return anything.Please help. There are no errors. I've even tried "cpbtxt.equals()" but still no luck. Please tell me where am I going wrong? Here is the complete code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.undo.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class Sample extends JFrame implements MenuListener
{
JMenuBar mb;
JMenu em;
JMenuItem paste;
JTextArea t;
public Sample()
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mb = new JMenuBar();
    em = new JMenu("Edit");
    paste = new JMenuItem("Paste");

    add(mb,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mb.add(em);
    em.add(paste);
    em.addMenuListener(this);

    t = new JTextArea();
    add(t,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public boolean canPaste() throws Exception
{
    Clipboard cpb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    String cpbtxt = (String)cpb.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    if(cpbtxt == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public void menuSelected(MenuEvent me)
{
    if(me.getSource() == em)
    {
        try {
        paste.setEnabled(canPaste());
        } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
}
public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent me)
  {
  }
public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent me)
  {
  }
}

class samplemain
{
public static void main(String[]args)
   {
    Sample s1 = new Sample();
    s1.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: "but it does not return anything" I can't reproduce this behavior. Please provide minimal but *complete* example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't swallow the exception.

Comment: em is a JMenu in the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `menuSelected` method like this:

```
public void menuSelected(MenuEvent me) {
    if(me.getSource() == em) {
        boolean canPasteResult = false;
        try {
            canPasteResult = canPaste();
        } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
        paste.setEnabled(canPasteResult);
    }
}
```

With your code this method didn't change the `enabled` state of the menuItem if your `canPaste` method throwed an Exception for example if you have selected a file in clipboard.
With my code this situation will result in a disabled state.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it is never **null**. Try this:

```
if(cpbtxt == null || cpbtxt.equals("")) {
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I've already tried this. It doesn't work either.